# java Process fails if process is ptrace ATTACH

Tags: java, linux, process, ptrace

I'm having the strangest problem: maybe someone can help out.

I have a daemon written in Java (I've tried the latest Java 8 both OpenJDK and Oracle) on Linux.  It will spawn some processes and there is a thread which watches to see if they're complete, meanwhile it will run other commands, some of which may kill the processes, etc.

Everything works absolutely fine almost all the time.  However, one of the operations that the daemon can perform on its subprocesses is it can grab a core from them (without killing them: a core of the active process).  It does this by loading a .so and calling it via JNI, which uses `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH...)` to pause the subprocess and grab core information, then it uses `ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH...)` to let it run again.

This also works fine and I can see the process operates correctly after the core has completed and all is fine.

Except, Java's `Process` object is now all wonky.  Whenever I invoke `exitValue()` on this process once this has happened I *always* get back and exit code of `4991` (which if you decode it, means `WIFSTOPPED` with a signal value of 19, or `SIGSTOP`).  That's not entirely surprising since the Linux man page states that ptrace() will look to parents as WIFSTOPPED.  But the problem is that once the `Process` object reaches this state, it will never do anything else, even though the process actually goes back to running after the detach.

Even more critically, even after the process really exits, `exitValue()` *still* returns 4991, and the process is not reaped (it lives on in Z (zombie) state, as defunct) and will never go away, until my daemon is killed whereupon init will inherit, and reap, the zombie processes.

I've looked at the value of `isAlive()` (says no) and I've tried to run `waitFor(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` (says not running) but none of them get `Process` out of this broken state--this doesn't surprise me too much since my reading suggests these methods are actually implemented in terms of the `exitValue()` method anyway.

This appears to me like a bug in Java `Process` but I'm not sure... I've tried reproducing it by attaching GDB to the process then detaching it, but that doesn't show the same problem.  Similarly just using SIGSTOP / SIGCONT doesn't do it.

Anyone have any hints or thoughts?

Comment: "Anyone have any thoughts?" - well, "you're brave". Interesting question. In the end, be prepared to rewrite your daemon in C++ or to patch OpenJDK if you can't fix your problem. Hope someone with time to dig into the OpenJDK source and with good Linux knowledge can help you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the jvm? Before you need to port to c/c++ :}